# How to get the size of a C function from inside a C program or with inline assembly?

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, elf, gnu-assembler

**Suppose I have a function like below:**

```
# cat 003.c

int foo(int a, int b)
{
    return a+b;
}
```

**And compile it like this:**

```
gcc -S 003.c
```

**The gets the following assembly result:**

```
     .file   "003.c"
     .text
 .globl foo
     .type   foo, @function
 foo:
 .LFB2:
     pushq   %rbp
 .LCFI0:
     movq    %rsp, %rbp
 .LCFI1:
     movl    %edi, -4(%rbp)
     movl    %esi, -8(%rbp)
     movl    -8(%rbp), %edx
     movl    -4(%rbp), %eax
     addl    %edx, %eax
     leave
     ret
 .LFE2:
     .size   foo, .-foo /* size of the function foo, how to get it?*/
```

The last line above do get the size of the function. Where does the compiler store the size? Can I get the function's size in some way in my origin C program using **C or inline asm**?

Comment: Unfortunately `__builtin_object_size` doesn't work (at least with gcc 4.7)

Comment: The size of symbols/objects may be part of the ELF symbol table. But to make it accessible to the program at runtime would require linker and of course assembler support. I have yet to see any evidence that the GNU assembler supports access to the size of a symbol. I believe there is simply no support in the GNU assembler and the GNU linker. The size is probably part of the symbol table solely for debugging purposes.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The information about a function size is stored in the *ELF Attributes* for the corresponding symbol (name). C example code how to parse this programmatically is at the bottom of the Solaris manpage for[`gelf_getsym(3ELF)`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19683-01/817-0679/6mgfb878e/index.html) (libelf does exist in Linux, *BSD and MacOS as well, you need to look for the `st_size` field of the `GElf_Sym` structure), but you also can use objdump / elfdump (Solaris) / readelf (Linux) for the task:

```
$ objdump -h -d --section=.text foo3.o

foo3.o:     file format elf64-x86-64

Sections:
Idx Name          Size      VMA               LMA               File off  Algn
  0 .text         00000012  0000000000000000  0000000000000000  00000040  2**2
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, CODE
[ ... ]
Disassembly of section .text:

0000000000000000 <foo>:
   0:   55                      push   %rbp
   1:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
   4:   89 7d fc                mov    %edi,0xfffffffffffffffc(%rbp)
   7:   89 75 f8                mov    %esi,0xfffffffffffffff8(%rbp)
   a:   8b 45 f8                mov    0xfffffffffffffff8(%rbp),%eax
   d:   03 45 fc                add    0xfffffffffffffffc(%rbp),%eax
  10:   c9                      leaveq
  11:   c3                      retq
```

This is for an unoptimized compile of your code, while the optimized version is:

```
$ objdump -h -d --section=.text foo3.o

foo3.o:     file format elf64-x86-64

Sections:
Idx Name          Size      VMA               LMA               File off  Algn
  0 .text         00000004  0000000000000000  0000000000000000  00000040  2**4
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, CODE
[ ... ]
Disassembly of section .text:

0000000000000000 <foo>:
   0:   8d 04 37                lea    (%rdi,%rsi,1),%eax
   3:   c3                      retq
```

Note the "Size" change from `0x12` to `4` ? That's what comes from the `.size` assembler directive.

The "trick" of trying to use inline assembly to give you function sizes / code locations isn't accounting for compiler-generated glue code (function entry prologues / exit epilogues, inline code generation, ...), nor for the compiler re-ordering inline assembly (gcc is notorious to do so), hence it's not generally a great idea to trust this. In the end, it depends on what exactly you're trying to do ...

**Edit:** A few more references, external as well as on stackoverflow:

1. From the gcc mailing list, [thread on `sizeof(function)`](http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-help/2003-07/msg00076.html)
2. [what does sizeof (function name) return?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2666392/what-does-sizeof-function-name-return)
3. [Find size of a function in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10966856/find-size-of-a-function-in-c)
4. [LibELF by example](http://sourceforge.net/projects/elftoolchain/files/Documentation/libelf-by-example/) sourceforge project (this is documentation / a tutorial)

Comment: I don't understand: the objdump output you quote shows the size of the text section, not individual functions. `readelf -s` however does show `st_size` attribute of symbols that you mention.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't take the difference of the pointer of the function and the current address at the end of the function ? Have a look at this question to recover the current IP address: [Get address of current instruction for x86](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7932287/get-address-of-current-instruction-for-x86), may be this code, [stolen form one of the reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7932378/566608):

```
unsigned long get_PC()
{
    unsigned long current_instruction;

    __asm__ __volatile__
    (
        "movq 8(%rbp), %rax\n\t"
        : "=a" (current_instruction)
    );

    return current_instruction;
}
```

would do the trick,

Comment: That's going to be very fragile, let alone portable.

Comment: not agree about the fragile in the sens of the idea, maybe the way you use to recover the address, AFAIK gcc should have some embedded way to get this, but I don't remember the name.

Comment: If you change optimization options or some code around, you can get results vastly different from the reality.

Comment: `return __builtin_return_address(0);` https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Return-Address.html

Comment: `__attribute__((__noinline__))` and `asm("");` https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html