# How to get Data Segment Size in C++

Tags: c++, data-segment

I need to do analysis of memory requirements of one library written in C++, because HW engineers need get some idea about memory requirements of our hardware, there are working on. I can measure heapsize peak, I can [measure stack size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1756285/stack-size-estimation), but I don't know how to estimate/measure [data segment size](http://www.inf.udec.cl/~leo/teoX.pdf) and Bss size. Is there any method in Visual Studio or GCC? I assume it will differs from compiler to compiler and from platform to platform, but an estimation is fine for me.

Comment: Have you tried just cross-compiling to your target platform and checking the produced binaries?

Comment: GCC (pedantically, GNU binutils) has a tool called [`size`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/size) for this.

Comment: I can cross-compile it for ARM in IAR Workbench. Do you mean that it should be possible to detect this from this IDE/tool somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

During the build:

- For VC++ run [`link.exe /map`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k7xkk3e2.aspx).
- For GCC run [`ld -Map`](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/Options.html#Options).

Both options generate a map file which will contain the segment sizes.

Answer (score 4):

There is a `size` utility.
E.g. for ARM MCU project it can be something like:

```
arm-none-eabi-size --format=sysv "program_name.elf"
```

Example output:

```
program_name.elf  :
section             size        addr
.text              14516           0
.data                160   268435456
.bss                1328   268435616
.stack              2528   268436944
.debug_aranges      2384           0
.debug_info        40951           0
.debug_abbrev       8870           0
.debug_line        27790           0
.debug_frame        6664           0
.debug_str         42157           0
.debug_loc          7074           0
.debug_macinfo    426030           0
.ARM.attributes       47           0
.debug_ranges       1760           0
.comment              96           0
.debug_macro        9236           0
Total             591591
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `objdump` to get the size of the text, data and bss segments on Linux systems. You can examine the output for the `.bss` and `.text` sections.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16820063/561300) for a more detailed explanation.