# How to print size of any function. This was asked before but answer was not particle?

Tags: c, sizeof

How to print size of any function? This question was asked but answer was not particle.
According to previous answer it is different, when I used built in function to find the size of function?

```
 #include<stdio.h>
 void print(void)
 {

    printf("i m in print \n");

 }
 int main()
 {
      printf("%d\n",(int)main-(int)print); // o/p is 20 byte  what is this 20    
                                           //is size of function?previous asked answer
      printf("size=%d\n",sizeof(print));// o/p is 1 byte ? how to get exact plz help?
 }
```

~

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4579589/2410359 is the closest you will get: an answer that somewhat works some of the time - which is effectively your first `printf()`.  A robust solution is not possible in C.

Comment: @mike W why u guys marked as duplicate i already mention it not particle i have gone throw it

Comment: Your post "How to print size of any function?"  has sub-questions "when I used built in function (`sizeof()`) to find the size of function?", "what is this 20?", "o/p is 1 byte ?",...  The duplicate only answers some of those questions.  I am confident other SO posts answer the remaining questions.  IAC, @Yu Hao answer explains well why `sizeof(print)` --> 1.  It is UB, any result is possible.  Some systems simple always return 1 on `sizeof(function)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Function do not generally exist as compact contiguous regions in memory. Which is why it is not possible to find size of a function. Functions do not have size.

Comment: can u please explain what   printf("%d\n",(int)main-(int)print); // what is this 20? and why sizeof is throwing 1 ?

Comment: please reply i am not able to figure out whats going in my code?

Comment: @Sumit Kumar: Your code prints the difference between two integer values obtained by implementation-defined conversion from function pointer type to `int` type. What does it mean? I have no idea. Probably the address difference between entry points of these two functions (which is generally not the "size" of any function). What your `sizeof` does I don't know either. Formally, it does not even compile. It is illegal to apply `sizeof` to functions. In other words, nothing meaningful is going on in your code. Trying to "figure it out" is a waste of time.

Answer (score 6):

`sizeof` on a function type violates the constraints of `sizoef` operator:

> C11 §6.5.3.4 The sizeof and _Alignof operators
>
> **The `sizeof` operator shall not be applied to an expression that has function type** or an
> incomplete type, to the parenthesized name of such a type, or to an expression that
> designates a bit-field member.

Comment: And so the code is non-portable.  The code appears to assume that functions have some kind of location in memory, but they needn't.  In a contrived example, a function pointer could be an index into a table and subtracting function pointers would have absolutely no resemblance to a notion such as "the number of bytes making up the machine-executable instructions for the translated function".  In a less contrived example, inline functions might be "found" in many places in the machine-executable instructions, instead of in one place.

Comment: @Shao: Even if a function is inlined in many places, if its address is ever taken, it has exactly one formal address.

Comment: R..: Agreed.  And which, of course we both know, would not occur for the **sizeof** case detailed by this answer, but does occur in the original post's code.

Comment: @Yu Hao  can u please explain what printf("%d\n",(int)main-(int)print); // what is this 20? and why sizeof is throwing 1 ?

Comment: @SumitKumar It's illegal code, nothing to explain.

Answer (score 0):

There is no guaranteed way of determining the size of a function at run-time (and little reason to do so).

Functions are part of text segment (which may or may not be 'heap') or its equivalent for the architecture you use. There's no data past compilation regarding their size, at most you can get their entry point from symbol table (which doesn't have to be available).  So you can't calculate their size in practice on most C environments you'll encounter.

Answer (score 0):

Generate an object file and then use `objdump -S foo.o` command to find the function size.